# How to get playlist name in youtube-dl?

Tags: shell, sh, youtube-dl

I can only find a command `youtube-dl --get-filename` to get a filename but cannot find one to get the playlist's name.

For example, if I use `youtube-dl --get-filename -o "%(title)s - %(id)s" "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL49CF3715CB9EF31D"`, it will return

```
Lec 1 _ MIT 18.06 Linear Algebra, Spring 2005 - ZK3O402wf1c
2. Elimination with Matrices. - QVKj3LADCnA
3. Multiplication and Inverse Matrices - FX4C-JpTFgY
Lec 4 _ MIT 18.06 Linear Algebra, Spring 2005 - 5hO3MrzPa0A
5. Transposes, Permutations, Spaces R^n - JibVXBElKL0
6. Column Space and Nullspace - 8o5Cmfpeo6g
7. Solving Ax = 0 - Pivot Variables, Special Solutions - VqP2tREMvt0
8. Solving Ax = b - Row Reduced Form R - 9Q1q7s1jTzU
9. Independence, Basis, and Dimension - yjBerM5jWsc
10. The Four Fundamental Subspaces - nHlE7EgJFds
11. Matrix Spaces; Rank 1; Small World Graphs - 2IdtqGM6KWU
12. Graphs, Networks, Incidence Matrices - 6-wh6yvk6uc
13. Quiz 1 Review - l88D4r74gtM
14. Orthogonal Vectors and Subspaces - YzZUIYRCE38
15. Projections onto Subspaces - Y_Ac6KiQ1t0
16. Projection Matrices and Least Squares - osh80YCg_GM
Lec 17 _ MIT 18.06 Linear Algebra, Spring 2005 - uNsCkP9mgRk
18. Properties of Determinants - srxexLishgY
19. Determinant Formulas and Cofactors - 23LLB9mNJvc
20. Cramer's Rule, Inverse Matrix, and Volume - QNpj-gOXW9M
Lec 21 _ MIT 18.06 Linear Algebra, Spring 2005 - lXNXrLcoerU
22. Diagonalization and Powers of A - 13r9QY6cmjc
23. Differential Equations and exp(At) - IZqwi0wJovM
Lec 24 _ MIT 18.06 Linear Algebra, Spring 2005 - 8MF3pz-oYHo
Lec 24b  _ MIT 18.06 Linear Algebra, Spring 2005 - sFxA8eIS6tA
Lec 25 _ MIT 18.06 Linear Algebra, Spring 2005 - umt6BB1nJ4w
26. Complex Matrices; Fast Fourier Transform - M0Sa8fLOajA
27. Positive Definite Matrices and Minima - vF7eyJ2g3kU
Lec 28 _ MIT 18.06 Linear Algebra, Spring 2005 - z_zYQHmrh08
Lec 29 _ MIT 18.06 Linear Algebra, Spring 2005 - Nx0lRBaXoz4
30. Linear Transformations and Their Matrices - Ts3o2I8_Mxc
Lec 31 _ MIT 18.06 Linear Algebra, Spring 2005 - vGkn-3NFGck
32. Quiz 3 Review - HgC1l_6ySkc
33. Left and Right Inverses; Pseudoinverse - Go2aLo7ZOlU
34. Final Course Review - RWvi4Vx4CDc
```

But not the Playlist's name `Gilbert Strang lectures on Linear Algebra (MIT)`

Answer (score 1):

`youtube-dl --get-filename -o "%(playlist_title)s - %(title)s - %(id)s" "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL49CF3715CB9EF31D"`

Also, there are other useful options:
`playlist`
`playlist_index`
`playlist_id`
`playlist_uploader`
`playlist_uploader_id`